# Arranging objects from most matching object to least matching object

Tags: c#

I am working on a problem in c#. I have an array of objects and one key object. There are five properties of an object:

1. Group
2. country
3. Service
4. Industry
5. Technology

I want to arrange objects such that most matching object with key object will be displayed first.
I want to arrange that data in following order -

1. It will get objects of same group as group of key object.
2. If objects of same group are found then these will be ordered according to country. i.e. If same parameter value is found then order will be decided according to next parameter.
3. Same process will be followed for objects with different groups also.

I have got one solution:
I created 32 linq queries with each permutation and combination of 5 parameters, then I merged those 32 results one by one. This solution gives me desired results but this solution needs a lot of processing. Please provide any shorter solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide any sample data with desired output? That will help us to understand things better.

Comment: So your LINQ query is something like `myObjects.OrderBy(o => o.Group).ThenBy(o => o.Country).ThenBy(o => o.Service).ThenBy(...)`? But you also want to change the ordering so you made various permutations of this LINQ query in code, so defined another one but it looks like: `myObjects.OrderBy(o => o.Group).ThenBy(o => o.Service).ThenBy(o => o.Technology).ThenBy(...)`? You would like to be able to define which ordering goes in which order arbitrarily without having to duplicate similar queries 32+ times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `OrderByDescending` + `ThenByDescending`:

```
var orderedObjects = objects
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Group == keyObj.Group)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Country == keyObj.Country)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Service == keyObj.Service)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Industry == keyObj.Industry)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Technology == keyObj.Technology)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Group) // now start ordering by the properties itself
    .ThenBy(o => o.Country)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Service)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Industry)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Technology)
    .ToArray();
```

The comparison returns `true` or `false` whereas `true` is "larger" than `false`, therefore `Descending` since we want matching properties first.

Answer (score 1):

What about giving points to each match with different weights?

A group match could be 100 points, a country 1000, a service 10000 ...

Then sort the items by their score.